# Is it possible to flush left equations using "numcases" or "subnumcases"?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I am wondering if it is possible in LaTeX to flush left equations when using the `numcases` or `subnumcases` environment provided by the `cases` package.

Hereafter I include a bit of code to explain the problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\tau = k \cdot i_a
\end{equation}
\begin{numcases}{v_a = }
v_s - k_1 \cdot (i_a - i) & if ia\\
v_p     &   if ia $\le$ i
\end{numcases}
\begin{subnumcases}{v_a = }
v_s - k_1 \cdot (i_a - i) & if ia\\
v_p     &   if ia $\le$ i
\end{subnumcases}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this code, you will see that the first equation is flushed left while the other two are not.
I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

The `cases` package has a `fleqn` option:

```
 \usepackage[fleqn]{cases}
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer. It works perfectly. May I ask you where did you find the information because this option does not appear in the "cases" package manual ?

Comment: I just loaded cases.sty into emacs and searched for fleqn:-)